# UILabel text is working on iPad 2 simulator but not on iPad Mini Simulators

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard

I Disabled auto layout in my storyboard by accident, after enabling it again I had to go through and resize all of my views and constraints, its a fairly big project. not good.

There have been some pretty strange things happening since re-enabling auto layout.

- My popovers looked odd on device and the UILabels and UITextfields inside them weren't conforming to the correct text colours, background colours or tints set in IB. I tried coding each of these swell to no avail.
- The popovers looked expected on iPad 2 simulator though. but not on iPad Air X simulators or iPad mini X simulators nor the real iPad Mini 2 device..
- Other ViewControllers are now being affected, UILabels in customCells are appearing as though the textColor properties are set to [UIColor clearColor]. Again they are appearing fine on iPad 2 simulator but not on iPad Air X or iPad Mini X simulators nor on my iPad Mini 2 real device.

I'm wondering whether disabling and enabling Auto Layout has damaged/corrupted storyboard.

Things I've tried.

- I've tried recreating the views and hooking them all up again appropriately. This seems to have solved the popover issue, but not the Clear UILabels in custom cells.
- I know that the UILabels are there because if i tick colour blended layers in simulator their blocks are showing in the correct places.
- Ive also tried cleaning the project and restarting Xcode etc.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Disabling autolayout would have removed all constraints. You need to set them again or hopefully you have project backups.

Comment: Yeah I ended up going into a back up, I replaced all the constraints I think the storyboard file must have been corrupted.

Comment: It's the primary feature, when you'll disable autolayout it will remove all the constraints. Enabling again will not bring back the constraints.

Comment: I understand that, this question is not about constraints. This is about UILabels text property appearing clear on certain devices. I checked the positioning of the label using the colour blended layers feature in simulator. hence why I wrote '' If I tick colour blended layers in simulator their blocks are showing in the correct places.'' So this is was not a constraint issue.